# TCP packet transmission time and frequency

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, packet

I am developing a application in linux about TCP packets transmission. Here is a function I may design: sender(time,packet_size,frequency,file). Parameter time stands for "How long it takes to transmit packets in second"; packet_size: "size of packet in KB"; frequency: "How many packets per second"; file: "a file to be transmitted". I am wondering where can I find the function or option or struct etc to implement this time and frequency control? And for the packet transmission in TCP, should I use socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,0) or socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,0) or any other option? I am fresher in linux programming, thanks for helping!!!

Comment: Are you going to use TCP with raw sockets ? Good luck. Btw there are no packets in TCP. it is a streaming protocol, the bytes that are received are acked.

Comment: What is your motivation for wanting to do this?  Knowing that might help people give you better answers.

Comment: The motivation is to develop a tool that sends 8KB(or bigger) blocks of data. requirements are:1. adjustable as a constant speed 2. unlimited speed 3. predefined goodput 4.using timestamps at sender and receiver and taking difference. 5.perfectly synchronized clocks or timestamp(receiver)-timestamp(sender).